# Java /Android what is faster than ArrayList?

Tags: java, android

What is faster than `ArrayList<String>` in Java ? I have a list which is of an undefined length. (sometimes 4 items, sometimes 100).

What is the FASTEST way to add and get it from any list ? `arrayList.add(string)` and `get()` are very slow.

Is there a better way for this? (`string s[]` and then `copyArray` are the slowest?)

Comment: I guess there is no faster way than array list for insertion and retrieval by index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Faster for what?

"basically arraylist.add(string) and get() is very slow." - based on what evidence?  And compared to what?   (No need for the word 'basically' here - it's a high tech "um".)  I doubt that ArrayList is the issue with your app.  Profiling your code is the only way to tell whether or not you're just guessing and grasping at straws.

Even an algorithm that's O(n^2) is likely to be adequate if the data set is small.

You have to understand the Big-Oh behavior of different data structures to answer this question.  Adding to the end of an ArrayList is pretty fast, unless you have to resize it.  Adding in the middle may take longer.

LinkedList will be faster to add in the middle, but you'll have to iterate to get to a particular element.

Comment: it ment to be appenden at the end which is very slow. I waited a long time (several seconds) to append a short number of 100 integers. that is really slow.

Comment: You've waited six months for this comment?  I think I've covered it with my answer.  See the part about "unless you have to resize it"?  Maybe you need to think about your initial size and resize behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Both `add()` to end of list and `get()` should run in O(1). And since length is undefined, you can't use a fixed length array. You can't do any better I'm afraid.

`add(int index, E element)` takes linear time for worst case though if that's why you think it's slow. If that is the case, either use Hashtable (insertion takes constant time) or TreeMap (insertion takes logarithmic time).

Answer (score 2):

100 items is not very many. Your bottleneck is elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look the [Jodd Utilities](http://jodd.org/doc/index.html). They have some collections that implement ArrayList but on primatives (jodd/util/collection/), such as IntArrayList.  So if you're creating a ArrayList of int, float, double, etc.. it will be faster and consume less memory.

Even faster than that is what they call a FastBuffer, which excels at add() and can provide a get() at O(1).

The classes have little interdependency, so it's easy to just drop in the class you need into your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javolution library. http://javolution.org

http://javolution.org/target/site/apidocs/javolution/util/FastList.html

ist much faster than arraylist ;)

Answer (score -5):

Try to use hashtable it is much faster