# Java - Is there any alternative, third-party Collections (ArrayList, etc.) libraries?

Tags: java, android, collections, arraylist

The story is that I'm now programming for Android.

I found that ArrayList is really slow, especially when used with adapters for listviews, as sorting and searching are required for my project. 
Is there any alternative library out there?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Define *"really slow"*. Maybe you want to look into JNI and use native libraries.

Comment: Have You tried http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/ it has lot of optimizations comparing to java classes?

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8324805/java-android-what-is-faster-than-arraylist

Comment: I shall be more specific - I'm developing an XMPP Chat app for Android. The major performance problem is on the buddy list screen.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As other answers have said, there are some alternative Collection libraries.

However, in core your problem might not be the library but rather your own choice of Collection. Using a different library, will not change this.

In Java, and thus Android, you have a vast array of Collection choices to your disposal, all with different pro's and cons.

This is a way to long story to write up, so unless you write down exactly what you want to do with it, no one can really tell you which choice is best. 
However, to give you a little start you could take a look at this;

[image: collection tree]

Comment: Wow! I love this diagram! Thank you so much! In fact I'm developing an XMPP Chat app for Android. The major performance problem is on the buddy list screen.

Comment: Why exactly is there a performance problem with that? I imagine it to be just a list of Contact objects you get back from the ContentProvider which you show in a ListView.. shouldn't really be a problem even if someone has hundreds of contacts, since the adapter takes care of loading only the visible ones + some extra for smooth scrolling..

Comment: That's because I'm using a third-party library (asmack) and the contact list is given as a Collection with codes such as [code] Collection<RosterEntry> entries = connection.getRoster().getEntries(); [/code]...

Comment: Hmm I did work with that library for a chat app and can't remember any real problems with performance on this part. You should just use the Roster info to save it in your own database, in the background ofcourse, and later when needed you load it from your database into any collection you like.

Answer (score 3):

Other than Collection framework in standard java API, below two are famous for their rich collection framework.

- [Google Guava Collections](https://code.google.com/p/google-collections/)
- [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/)

Answer (score 0):

You can sort and search just fine with the existing Java collections.  I see no need for anything else.

But there are alternatives, like Google Collections and Apache Commons stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Drawback of ArrayList is that you cannot store primitives in it.
Leading to much more memory usage compared to an array.
In Situation where you have very huge arrays (e.g > ten or hundred thousands elemts)
a growing primitive array is often the better solution.

This article shows to implement your own [ArrayListLong](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0140__Collections/ArrayListforintegerobjects.htm) using primitive types: